# Cannot access UICollectionView element

Tags: xcode7, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

Trying to automate some UI tests with Xcode 7.2 and the XCT UI FW.

View hierarchy is as follows:

```
SearchViewController
   UIView
      UITableView
         CustomCell:UITableViewCell
            UIView
               UILabel
               UICollectionView
                  CustomCell:UICollectionViewCell
                     UILabel
                     UIImageView
         CustomCell:UITableViewCell
            .
            .
```

My problem is that I cannot access anything within the UICollectionView, nor can I actually access the UICollectionView itself (or verify that it exists).

Here some lldb cmds and output:

```
po app.tables.cells.count   3
```

As expected since I three of CustomCell:UITableViewCell

```
po app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(0).staticTexts.count   1
```

Returning 1 for the UILabel within the first CustomCell:UITableViewCell. But should it not also include the UILabel further down the tree, inside the UICollectionViewCells since the .elementType notation is short for descendantsMatchingType(.elementType)?

```
po app.tables.collectionViews.count   0
po app.tables.cells.collectionViews.element.exists   false
```

As you can see I cannot access the UICollectionView. When building and testing the app there are 8 UICollectionViewCells within each UITableViewCell and I have set the the Accessibility checkbox to enabled in Xcode.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what give you "app.collectionViews.count" ?

Comment: @Che app.collectionViews.count gives me 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify cells within collection views in this fashion. Just replace 'sampletext' with any static text that uniquely identifies that cell.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'sampletext'")
let cell = XCUIApplication().collectionViews.cells.element(matching: predicate)
```